# Proxy between private PyPi and public

Tags: python, pypi

Previously I worked on a Node.js project I ran a private npm registry and used [PayPal's Kappa](https://github.com/krakenjs/kappa) to proxy between this and the public npm registry. I also used an npmrc file in each project to define the url of the registry. Now when developers checkout the projects and run  `npm install` the request will go to Kappa which first looks in the local registry and if it doesn't find the matching module it forwards the request to the public registry.

Is there anyway to achieve this with Python projects. Ideally I'd like the developers to simple check out a service and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` without knowing if the dependencies are coming from public or private PyPi.